# Fastest way to get ONLY unique values from array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, time-complexity

I have an array like this

```
students = [{name: 'Abbey', age: 25}, {name: 'Brian', age: 45},
            {name: 'Colin', age: 25}, {name: 'Dan', age: 78}]
```

and I want the output to be;

```
uniqueAges = [45, 78]
```

To be clear, if there is an age value that appears more than once in the students array, I do not want **any** of the objects with that age in my uniqueAges array. 'Abbey' and 'Colin' have the same age so they are **both** out.

I know I can do something like this and run `uniqueAgeGetter(students)`

```
   function uniqueAgeGetter(list){
   var listCopy = list.slice();
   var uniqueAges = list.slice();
   for (var i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (var j = listCopy.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if(listCopy[j].name !== list[i].name && 
                listCopy[j].age == list[i].age){
                  uniqueAges.splice(i, 1)
                }   
            }
    }
   console.log(uniqueAges)
   return uniqueAges
 }
```

But is it possible to do it without a second loop? I'm not an expert on time complexity but I am trying to find if it is possible this task can be O(n).

Edit:
I am not asking if `uniqueAgeGetter` be rewritten to read nicer or use functions like map, reduce or filter (as my understanding is they are ultimately a loop as well).

My question is can uniqueAgeGetter be refactored in a way that reduces the time complexity? Can it be done with only one loop?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to use **Set**

Comment: @oybek `Set` is great, but it is not widely supported yet

Comment: As has been shown, `O(n)` complexity is quite possible. But getting an output of a well-formed *array* `[45, 78]` is not possible *in a single iteration* over all elements. (All the solutions here require more than one iteration over multiple elements) However, it *would* be possible to get the desired output in a Set while iterating over elements only once. Is that something you're interested in?

Comment: @Victor The vast majority of browsers support Sets. They're an ES2015 feature, and for the most part, only the *very* obsolete browsers which do not get updated do not understand Sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The first idea, we can do over two step:

  Step1:  Sort the array

  -- There are many algorithms to do it. As I know, currently, the complexity of best algorithm now is O(Nlog(N)) with N is the number of array.

  Step2: Remove the duplicated elements

  -- The complexity of this step is O(N)
  So, over two steps, the complexity is O(N) + O(Nlog(N)). Finally, the complexity is O(Nlog(N))
- The second idea

  This also has the complexity is O(Nlog(N)) but it will be O(N) for next time you want to get the unique age.

  Instead of saving the data in array, you can rebuild in a binary search tree with a little custom. This node in this tree will save all the elements with same age.

  The complexity for the first time you build the tree is O(Nlog(N))

About the algorithm which has the complexity is O(N), currently, I think there are no technique to solve it. :D

Answer (score 6):

This can be done in `O(n)` time by counting the number of times an age has been seen, and filtering out the ages with a count more than one.

Since ages have reasonable limits, we can use an integer array of length equal to the maximum possible age to store the age counts. In the example below, I take the maximum possible age to be a comfortable `200`.

```js
var students = [
  {name: 'Abbey', age: 25 }, 
  {name: 'Brian', age: 45 },
  {name: 'Colin', age: 25 }, 
  {name: 'Dan', age: 78 }
];

var studentAges = students.map(val => val.age);
var ageCounts = Array(200).fill(0);

studentAges.forEach(age => ageCounts[age] += 1);

var uniqueAges = studentAges.filter(age => ageCounts[age] == 1);

console.log(uniqueAges);
```

Comment: Using an object or `Map` and initialising only the values that appear in the array might be faster and won't fail if the assumptions (like age being an integer between 0 and 200) are not met.

Comment: Valid point about not requiring assumptions, @Bergi. However, I do not believe that using a map will necessarily be faster, especially for larger inputs. The time spent hashing and rehashing and resolving hash collisions should outweigh any performance benefits (which I cannot see any of - maybe I am missing something?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce`

The first `reduce` is to summarise the array and convert it into  an object using the age as a the key. Using the age as the key will make it easier to check if the age already exist. The object properties will have an array value like `[2,true]`, where the first element is the age and the second element tells if the age has duplicates. Using  `Object.values` will convert the object into an array.

The second `reduce` is to form the desired output.

```js
let students = [{name: 'Abbey', age: 25 }, {name: 'Brian', age: 45 },{name: 'Colin', age: 25 }, {name: 'Dan', age: 78 }];

let uniqueAges = Object.values(students.reduce((c, v) => {
  if (c[v.age] === undefined) c[v.age] = [v.age, true];
  else c[v.age][1] = false;
  return c;
}, {})).reduce((c, v) => {
  if (v[1]) c.push(v[0]);
  return c;
}, []);

console.log(uniqueAges);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However it is my understanding that reduce iterates over the elements in the same way as a loop, so does not make the time complexity of the function any faster. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Well If you are getting this from DB, you might want to query the unique values. If you are using js, You have iterates to achieve what you need (well, as far as i know.)

Comment: Please explain in your answer what your code does with that `v` object and the tuples in it, and why you used `Object.values`, and how the reduction on the `c` array works. That you "*can use `reduce`*" is not relevant, the same general approach can be used with any other form of looping.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you could do it. I think the time complexity would be `O(n^2)` where `n` is the number of elements in the original array and `m` is the number of unique elements in the output array.

```js
const students = [
  {name: 'Abbey', age: 25 }, 
  {name: 'Brian', age: 45 },
  {name: 'Colin', age: 25 }, 
  {name: 'Dan', age: 78 }
];

const uniqueStudents = students.map(val => val.age)
  .sort()
  .reduce((current, next) => {
    return current.length === 0 ? [].concat(current, next)
      : current[current.length - 1] !== next ? [].concat(current, next)
        : current.slice(0, -1);
  }, []);
  
console.log(uniqueStudents);
```

Comment: As far as I know, JavaScript array sort is O(n log n).

Comment: @גלעדברקן => After some additional reading, you are correct. In that case, I am really not sure what the complexity of this would actually be. :S

Comment: I think that without the `slice`, the dominant complexity would be the sort so `O(n log n)`. But each call to `slice` makes a copy so that has a potential of `O(n^2)` since current would be iterated over on each call of `slice`.

Comment: @גלעדברקן => Good call. I will update my response with that then.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way with a single iteration.

```js
const students = [
  {name: `Abbey`, age: 25}, 
  {name: `Brian`, age: 45},
  {name: `Colin`, age: 25}, 
  {name: `Dan`, age: 78},
  {name: `Dan`, age: 25}
]

// no global variables
function unique(key) {
  const occurrences = {}
  const list = {}
  return (result, next, index, {length}) => {
    const value = next[key]
    if (list[value]) {
      occurrences[value] = value
    }
    else {
      list[value] = value
      result.push(value)
    }
    return index === length - 1 ? result.filter(v => !occurrences[v]) : result
  }
}

const uniqueNames = students.reduce(unique(`name`), [])
const uniqueAges = students.reduce(unique(`age`), [])

console.log(uniqueAges)
```

Comment: This actually iterates over every element twice, for `O(2n)` complexity (same as `O(n)` complexity, but yours *does* require two iterations - once for every `reduce` callback, and once at the very end when you `filter`). This also can't differentiate between non-strings which look the same when coerced to a string, eg `54` and `'54'`.

Answer (score 1):

for getting unique elements

```js
const data = [128, 128,128,121,127,127,121,121,121,121,122,125];
const uniqueData = Object.keys(data.reduce((r,c) => {r[c] = true; return r;}, {}))
console.log(uniqueData)
```

But doing this will sort the array and will not keep the original order of the array

Complexity `O(n)`

Comment: Or just do: const uniqArray = Array.from(new Set(array));